# get object out of telerik radcontrol for winforms binding

Tags: winforms, data-binding, binding, listbox, telerik

I hope that someone can help me with an issue related to binding a bindable collection class to one of the Winforms Telerik list controls.

If you bind to a plain ole windows list control like this...

```
dim list as new listBox

with list
    .DataSource=myCollectionClass  'this contains a collection of widgets.
    .ValueMember="WidgetID"
    .DisplayMember="WidgetName"
end with
```

I can then get a widget out of the list by doing this...

```
Dim myWidget as Widget=ctype(list.Items(0),Widget)
```

If you do the exact same code with for example a Telerik RadListBox (same example as above)
but change line one to be

```
Dim list as new RadListBox.
```

With RadControls it seems you cannot cast to the Object type directly.  Whenever I try this I get the following error...

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListBoxItem' 
to type 'Widget'.
```

Can someone at the least confirm that this is a known limitation of Telerik RadControls for Winforms or let me know the proper way to do it.

Thanks.  Any help will be appreciated.  Any thoughts?

Seth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked this question on the Telerik forum.  Here is the answer I got...

"You can take the data bound item by the DataItem property that RadComboBoxItem exposes. For example:"

```
Me.Text = (CType((CType(Me.RadComboBox1.SelectedItem, RadComboBoxItem)).DataItem, Employee)).Phone
```

Seth